# How to erase an element in a vector of vector or matrix

Tags: c++

Hey there I am trying to erase an element in a vector of vector / most probably a matrix made of vector so I searched stack overflow but it didn't have any answers and I wasn't able to find it online as well so thought to ask here.Well I am new to programming and I'm trying to solve google kick start 2020 Round-A [QUESTION](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc7/00000000001d40bb).

So I have written a code, which acts similar as a stack well I didn't used stack but tried implement it using vector but unable to erase element in i'th vectors n'th position.

CODE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#define ans(x,y) "Case #"<<x<<": "<<y<<"\n"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    #endif
    int TC;
    cin>>TC;
    int k=1;
    while(TC--){
        int Stacks,Plates,Max;
        cin>>Stacks>>Plates>>Max;
        vector<vector<int>>S_Plates;
        for(int i=0;i<Stacks;i++){
            vector<int>vec;
            for(int j=0;j<Plates;j++){
                int Dat;
                cin>>Dat;
                vec.push_back(Dat);
            }
            S_Plates.push_back(vec);
        }
        int Cnt=0,Beauty=0;
        while(Cnt!=Plates){
            int mx=0;
            int SNo=0;
            for(int i=0;i<Stacks;i++){
                mx=(mx,S_Plates[i][0]);
                if(mx==S_Plates[i][0])
                    SNo=i;
            }
            Beauty+=(mx);
        // Well Got Stucked Here    S_Plates.erase(S_Plates.begin()+SNo[0]);
            Cnt++;
        }
        cout<<ans(k,Beauty);
        k++;
    }
}
```

Well in order to understand the code pls refer to the question I have linked above.

So please let me know how can I do that.

PS:
Sorry for bad English
And Bad Code

Comment: whats wrong with the code? What happens when you have `S_Plates.erase(S_Plates.begin()+SNo[0]);` in the code? Compiler error? Runtime error? Unexpected output?

Comment: `SNo` is an `int`. What was the intention when you wrote `SNo[0]` ?

Comment: Well S_Plates is an vector and every index has its vector inside it, SNo is the ith index that I want to access and when I try to access 0th element of i'th vector as you knowsubscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 my intention was to access the 0th element of ith vector but idk how to do it

Comment: `SNo` is a single `int` it has no elements

Comment: Let me explain it's a matrix SNo Is The Column Which I Want To Access

Comment: `S_Plates.erase(S_Plates.begin()+ x );` erases the x-th element from the vector. `SNo[0]` just doesnt make sense, but that has nothing to do with erasing an element from a vector

Comment: this is probably another typo: `mx=(mx,S_Plates[i][0]);`. Did you want to get the maximum of the two or something like that? As written its the same as `mx = S_Plates[i][0];` which makes the condition on the next line `true` always

Comment: Well @largest_prime_is_463035818 without erasing the vector it works fine but the deal is that I need to find the maximum element of 0th index of every row and after each iteration I want to erase the maximum number

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 in order to understand what I did pls refer the question :)

Comment: you want to erase one element from the inner vector? Note that your title says something else. Erasing an element from a vector of vectors is  what `S_Plates.erase(S_Plates.begin()+ x );` does. If you want to erase an element from a vector that is inside a vector you do that in the same way as if the vector was not inside another vector: `my_vector.erase( iterator_to_element_to_be_erased);`

Comment: Well in order to make it most simplest I have a matrix made up of vector and for ex- I want to erase element of 2nd column, 0th row of the matrix

Comment: Well thanks I'll change the title :)

Comment: Note that erasing is a costly function, and useless here (you could use indices). Moreover, I am not convinced that this greedy algorithm will provide the best result. For example, consider `P=2; S[0] = {1, 100}, S[1]={2, 2}, S[2] = {2, 2}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erasing can be performed as:

```
S_Plates[SNo].erase(S_Plates[SNo].begin());
```

A few modifications are needed elsewhere, as indicated in comments.

Note that erasing is a costly function, and useless here: you could use indices instead. (one per stack)

However, this greedy algorithm does not provide the good result. For example, consider

```
Stacks (N) = 3; Plates (K) = 2; Max (P) = 2; 
S[0] = {1, 100}, S[1]={2, 2}, S[2] = {2, 2}
```

Your program returns 4 instead of 101.

The solution is to implement a DP algorithm.

Let us defined an array `Cumul[N][P]` initialised to 0.

Then

```
i = 0 to N-2
Cumul[i+1][j] = max (Cumul[i][j], Cumul[i][j-k], A[i][0] + .. A[i][k-1]), for j =0 to P and k = 0 to K
```

Complexity is O(PNK).